# Stuck at async method

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

There maybe some obvious mistake but I'm doing something not experienced with. I'm trying to get a string from internet but its not working. In WinRT, we have to use HttpClient in async method, which I did as follows:-

```
    private async void update()
    {
        try
        {   
                rawdata = await client.GetStringAsync(url);     

        }
        catch
        {
            rawdata = "Updation failed. Error code:vish42042";
        }

      }
```

Now, here is how the code is called:-

```
    string temp = @url;
                update();
          WAIT:
                if (rawdata == null) {
                    goto WAIT;
                }
```

rawdata is a global varible, I did this checking on goto WAIT: to see where exactly was code failing, and its failing here. I'm expecting the if loop to break when rawdata is updated from the internet, but it never happens. Am I doing it the wrong way?(OBVIOUSLY I'm not doing it in the best way I know, but is it wrong too?). Where is the problem?

Update: Actually the problem is not HOW TO MAKE THIS FUNCTION WORK, it is working with a modification or two. The real problem is how do I make sure that rawdata is updated once update() function is called, because the code thereafter is expecting it not to be null but updated.

After some very good explanations and answers, I think then this is the point where problem can be solved:-

```
     string xmlstring = xmlupobj.getUpdatedData(); 
     // Above is the ultimate point of return of data. 
    //Next code line is this, which throws a null exception 
                    XDocument xmldoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring);
```

So I think after making getUpdatedData() async, returning Task, if we can convert Task to proper string in case it has been downloaded, and null if it has not been downloaded, then we can check using some bad lines of code as:-

```
    string xmlstring = xmlupobj.getUpdatedData();
    WAIT:
        if (xmlstring == null)
        {
            goto WAIT;
        }
        xmldoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring);
```

So if it is right, the only question remains is how to set xmlstring?

Comment: @torrentialcoding I have no idea why your edit suggestion was rejected, it was clearly valid. I hope you don't mind me pushing your edit under my name.

Comment: @hvd No problem, restoring it was the right thing to do regardless of who is attributed for the edit. :)

Comment: Even if you *could* do what you wanted (*wait* for update() to complete) you app would block the main thread and fail certification.

Comment: To your edit, you're still trying to do a busy wait in which you loop while your variable isn't set.  **Don't do that**.  It's horrendously resource intensive, and as it is it won't even work.  You should modify `update` to return a `Task<string>`, using the implementation Reed showed you, and then modify the caller to return a `Task` (or `Task<Something>` as well after parsing the XML and doing whatever with it.

Answer (score 3):

You should make this method return a `Task`:

```
private async Task update()
{
    try
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            rawdata = await client.GetStringAsync(url);     
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        rawdata = "Updation failed. Error code:vish42042";
    }
}
```

Then when you call it:

```
string temp = @url;
await update();

// rawdata will be set here
```

---

Another option would be to return the string directly, instead of setting it in a variable:

```
private async Task<string> UpdateAsync()
{
    try
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            return await client.GetStringAsync(url);     
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return "Updation failed. Error code:vish42042";
    }
}
```

You could then get your data via:

```
string rawdata = await UpdateAsync();
```

Note that both of these methods require the caller to be an `async` method, as well.

Comment: Better yet, change it to return a `Task<string>` rather than modifying a global variable.

Comment: I tried it.Sorry but then it gives an error that await keyword can only be used in async method. So then I'll have to make that method async too??

Comment: @vish213 Yes - you would need that to be an async method, too

Comment: Actually the problem is not HOW TO MAKE THIS FUNCTION WORK, the real problem is how do I make sure that rawdata is updated once update() function is called, i.e. the code thereafter is expecting it not to be null but updated

Comment: @vish213 If you make the caller an async method, rawdata would be guaranteed to update.  Personally, I'd use the second option above - set rawdata based on the results, but either would work.

Comment: @vish213 You can't get around the fact that you need to either make the caller async OR block on the results, though - that's the entire point of making this method async.

Comment: I still don't understand. Even if I make the caller async, then the results returned would be Task<string>, which need to be collected using await keyword, which again can only be used in async methods??

Comment: @vish213 Yes, which is what creates the concept of "async all the way up".  You don't just make one low level method async, you make * everything* async all the way up the chain.  That's unavoidable.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your update:

> Actually the problem is not HOW TO MAKE THIS FUNCTION WORK, it is working with a modification or two. The real problem is how do I make sure that rawdata is updated once update() function is called, because the code thereafter is expecting it not to be null but updated.

The answer is simple.  **You can't**.

The entire purpose of making the method asynchronous is that calling `update` will not set the value right then an there, it will start some unit of work that will set it *at some unknown point in the future* while letting you continue on with the program instead of waiting.  In order to ensure that the variable is set before `update` returns you need to make the method synchronous, and wait inside of the method for a value to exist, instead of using asynchrony.

If you would like to keep `update` asychronous then you'll need to make some simple modifications, as indicated in [Reed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16067162/1159478) to allow the caller to be notified of when the result has been computed, and then you can either `await` the method, or manually add a continuation using `ContinueWith`, to execute the desired code once the result has been computed.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. Actually I developed a WPF app, and now I'm just converting it into WinRT app. My method in WPF was obviously synchronous, but because of the limitation in WinRT that we cannot use WebClient in synchronous method, all I'm trying is to find the best alternative.

Comment: @vish213 The best alternative is to make your code “`async` all the way up”, as was already mentioned by others.